# Groovy method naming convention in terms of defining our own DSL

Tags: groovy, dsl

I try to create a small DSL, but i'm struggling with even simple stuff.
The following script gives me an error.

```
def DEMON(String input) {
  ['a': input]
}
DEMON 'Hello thingy' a
```

For some reasons, the parentheses around the parameters are not optional and i get an error.
This script runs fine:

```
def dEMON(String input) {
  ['a': input]
}
dEMON 'Hello thingy' a
```

Note: the only difference is the lowercase first char. 
So what is going on here? Why are the scripts interpreted (compiled?) different? Is there some kind of method/class naming schemes i have to follow?

Update: The error message. I guess a Syntax error:

```
unexpected token: Hello thingy @ line 4, column 7.
```

Comment: I probably won't have the answer anyway, but when asking about an error, post the error.

Comment: @JB Nizet Sorry, added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The groovy syntax is sometime complex, and the compiler use some rules to choose what it must do. One of this rule is simple : If a word starts with an uppercase, it's probably a class.

for example, `f String` is a syntax valid in groovy, and the compiler converts it to `f(String.class)`.

you can use parenthesis to help groovy understand your `DEMON` is not a class but a method, `DEMON('Hello thingy', a)`

Comment: Well, ok. So the compiler can't determine DEMON to be a method based on the definition? Can i change the definition in a way, so that i can keep the uppercase name and don't have to use parentheses?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It fails in the "parsing" stage : the first AST stage, where the semantic or context is not used. The grammar rejects this construction.